# Selenium+Python Youtube close driver after video finish playing

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

Hi I am trying to play YouTube using selenium and python. its easy to get played, but i got trouble to close driver after video finish playing. I have tried my script to get text but not really working.

```
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'My Video title')]")) 
        )

    except:
        break
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

code above is to close after video title is change, but only working when i refresh the page. May be somebody can help with this code or may have another elegant method to do the job

Comment: Maybe you could incorporate using driver.refresh()

Comment: i need the video finish playing first

Answer (score 0):

You could force it to quit using the exit function of the os library `os.exit(0)`
(for alternatives to `os.exit(0)` see [geeks for geeks  python exit commands](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-exit-commands-quit-exit-sys-exit-and-os-_exit/)), but that would terminate the entire program which I am not quite sure that you want to do.

Comment: i need to wait for video finish playing, so maybe i should use title change or url change

Comment: you could do a time.sleep() that sleeps the amount of time the video is perhaps and then exit

Comment: thats an alternatif, but i can get the exact time of video, also there are some ads showing,

Comment: Just throwing it out there, have you considered using the Youtube API?